# Problems with check-out in ALM 11 REST API

Tags: java, rest, alm

I think I am doing everything right according to the documentations I have, but I still get an error 406 with the message "Not Acceptable" when trying to check-out a test.

The steps I do are:

- authenticate OK
- read items and find the id of the one I want to update OK
- lock my item OK
- check-out --> 406

I am checking out using the following URL:
http://myHost/qcbin/rest/domains/DEFAULT/projects/myProject/tests/4313/versions/check-out

I am not sending a versions XML since the documentation says that it's not needed when checking out the last version.

Here is my code:

```
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    String url = Properties.get("hpqc.base_url") + DOMAINS + Properties.get("hpqc.domain") + PROJECTS
            + Properties.get("hpqc.project") + TEST_PUT + id + VERSIONS + reservationType;
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept:", "application/xml");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost, context);
    printHttpStatus(response);
    printResponse(response);
```

alternatively I also have tried to add a version XML by adding these lines:

```
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type:", "application/xml");
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(versionXml, "utf-8"));
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: are you passing payload with this request? like <CheckOutParameters>
    <VersionParameters>
    <Comment>Entity Check-out by gaurav for test</Comment>
    </VersionParameters>
    </CheckOutParameters>

Answer (score 0):

The setHeader methods used in the above piece of code contain colons (as in "Content-Type **:**"). The colons are redundant.

Try removing both colons in the setHeader methods and run again.